# Would like to understand this error message. Typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') js:6

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code that will generate a random option from an array as a computer selection, but I keep getting an error code. The error code is this: Typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). Below is the code that I have written. Thank you in advance. I'm fairly new to coding so please let me know if there is anything that I can improve.

```
let x = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors'];
function getComputerChoice(x){
const random = Math.floor(Math.random()* x.length);
  console.log(x[random]);
}
```

Comment: You're not passing an argument when you call the function, so `x` is undefined.

Comment: You need to call `getComputerChoice(x)` to pass the array as an argument.

Comment: Right, I have that outside of my function right afterwards. It is still popping an error message

Comment: Or define `getComputerChoice` to take no argument. A simple search of that error message would have found plenty of matches.